# HTML Form Submit To PHP Select Not Working

Tags: php, html, forms, select, submit

Yeah so my HTML code is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Compare Master - The Master at System Comparison! </title>
</head>
<body>
Select a GPU you want to compare: <br>
<form action="compare.php" method="GET">
<select name="lelo" id="lelo">
 <optgroup label="Radeon HD Series">
  <option name="Radeon3470" value="Radeon3470">Radeon HD 3470</option>
  <option name="Radeon3650" value="Radeon3650">Radeon HD 3650</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Radeon R7 Series">
  <option name="R7240" value="R7240">Radeon R7 240</option>
  <option name="R7250" value="R7250">Radeon R7 250</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php
    $gpu1 = $_GET['lelo'];
    echo $gpu1;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

and what I want is, when the form is submitted, I want the PHP to display on the page what the user selected from the "lelo" select and submitted it to it.

Comment: `<option>` does not have name attributes; remove them. Also use `isset()`.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work again

Comment: Take it up with the answer given below, which is exactly what I said above. Only, I didn't write it all out, or is that "removed" them all out ;-)

Comment: Tried it. Still nothing on PHP

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is enabled on your server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard OP's using `file://` ;-) now that's an easy fix. See if the answer below gives the fix.

Comment: I already edited my HTML as fcastillo posted but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is bad because the name attribute for the select can`t be in the option

```
<select name="lelo" id="lelo">
 <optgroup label="Radeon HD Series">
  <option value="Radeon3470">Radeon HD 3470</option>
  <option value="Radeon3650">Radeon HD 3650</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Radeon R7 Series">
  <option value="R7240">Radeon R7 240</option>
  <option value="R7250">Radeon R7 250</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Still, my PHP page doesn't show anything

Comment: If you enter in your url... yourdomain.com/compare.php?lelo=Radeon3650  What happend? Can you see that this page print Radeon3650?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/HTML/comparemaster/compare.php?lelo=Radeon3650&submit=submit it prints this

Comment: Ok, and do you have a PHP server installed? I recomend you that install [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) in your PC so you can test PHP code.

Comment: Thing is, this "thing" that I try to make is for a school project that we are doing and I don't want to run it on some server cause on the school's PC there won't be a server to run it on

Comment: Without a server you cannot run PHP. You should be able to install a server on your machine @XrhstosSDrougouths

Comment: But you need a PHP server. Could you take your computer to school... or  you could search about free hosting and maybe you could upload and test your code.